# Change depth of indentation in vi

Tags: vi, editing

What's the easiest way to increase or decrease indentation for a large block of code in vi?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In vim (not sure if this applies to you too), you use `>>` to indent one line.  As with nearly every command in vim, type in a number before the command to perform is multiple times.  So to indent the next 50 lines, type `50>>`.

Answer (score 9):

Autoidenting:

For a { } block I use the command: **=iB** (with the cursor inside the block to ident)

For re-identing a complete file, I use **gg=G**

Now for increase or decrease identation on a block, you have to select it (I use **viB** command) and then you do **>>** or **<<** and if you want to repeat the identation just use the dot **.**

Also remember to set your identation settings with

**:set shiftwidth=NUMOFSPACES**

and

**:set softtabstop=NUMOFSPACES**

Answer (score 3):

Mark it, then use > and <.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is between curly braces, then put your cursor on one of the curly braces and use `>%` or `<%`.

Answer (score 2):

By default in insert mode, you can use `Ctrl-T` and `Ctrl-D` to de-/intent the current line.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful command is, once you indent using '<' or '>', use '.' to repeat the command until it's lined up how you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can look at http://vim.wikia.com/ for tips on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

hit v to go into visual mode and arrow down so the whole block is selected then 12>>

Answer (score 0):

use two angle-brackets ("<<" or ">>") for one line left or right by shiftwidth characters. You can do this with the common line-range indicators - ":m,n", brace/bracket/paren matching, etc.

Or "<", then a motion indicator, then another "<".

Or "<12<" shifts the next 12 lines left.

Answer (score 0):

:50,100>

Will indent lines 50 through 100 once

:50,100>>

Will indent lines 50 through 100 twice

also works with < and << etc.

Answer (score 0):

First find the line numbers of the start and end lines using the Control-g command. Let these be *m* and *n*. Suppose we wish to indent line numbers *m* through *n* by 5 spaces. Then, the following command does the job,

```
:m,ns/^/     /g
```

To decrease the indentation, first convert all tabs to (say 4) spaces.

```
:m,ns/\t/    /g
```

Then let's say we wish to remove 3 spaces from lines numbered *m* through *n*.

```
:m,ns/^   //g
```